# Is my data normally distributed?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, gaussian-process, normality-assumption

> shapiro.test(U_ER)

```
Shapiro-Wilk normality test
```

data:  U_ER
W = 0.98093, p-value = 0.002173

> agostino.test(U_ER)

```
D'Agostino skewness test
```

data:  U_ER
skew = 0.0057972, z = 0.0381773, p-value = 0.9695
alternative hypothesis: data have a skewness

given the test, indicating the different results, can I consider my variable U_ER as normally distributed and use the variable for further analysis?

Comment: 1. Failing to reject in a test of normality does not tell you that your values were drawn from a normal population. Don't confuse a lack of rejection with a positive absence of effect. 2. A test of assumptions is typically not useful; you won't (likely ever) have an assumption hold exactly, so a null that asserts it will always be false, but may be inconsequential; it's better to focus on the consequences of the null being false (potential effect size,  robustness of the procedure to it) than the fact of it.  . . . ctd

Comment: ctd . . . 3. Not having a variable being normally distributed is typically irrelevant (e.g. it's not at all relevant in regression, for example, where none of the original variables need to be marginally normal), even when you have some inferential procedure based on a normality assumption. 4. Non-normality shouldn't be a barrier - just choose a suitable assumption for your variables, if any assumption is needed at all. You should probably begin by explaining what the analysis you want to do is, and what your variable measures.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for clarifying. actually, I am working on a network structure among the various uncertainties related to the economy using abn package in R. Given my understanding I needed to mention them as Gaussian distribution. And as the variables are related to uncertainty(which only shows very higher spikes very few times), I am not sure about completely transforming them into a normal distribution. So I kind of thinking agostino.test which checks skewness is enough for using them in further analysis.

Comment: ctd...  and while exploring google, I came across this, "Unlike the D'Agostino-Pearson test, the Shapiro-Wilk test doesn't use the shape of the distribution to determine whether or not it is normal. Instead, it compares the actual SD of the data to the SD computed from the slope of the QQ plot for the data, and calculates their ratio." So I am kind of confused about it. if possible, let me know if I am wrong or right and why

Comment: 1. From [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/abn/index.html): "An additive Bayesian network model consists of a form of a DAG where each node comprises a generalized linear model, GLM." ... so far I don't see any need for assuming even conditional normality. ...  2. Looking at the paper [here](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v105i08) even if you did use a normal model for some components, (as I suggested above already) it wouldn't  necessarily imply that the marginal distribution would be normal. As already explained, I see no benefit in any of the tests you mention. ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... If you think the conditional assumption for the variable in the network would be wrong, why not choose a different family in the GLM for it?

Comment: Many posts on site discuss the distinction between the conditional distribution assumptions of many common models (including regressions and GLMs) vs marginal distributions, and why examining the raw variable may be quite misleading.

Comment: have you considered looking at the qqplot against the normal distribution. Normally tests tend to be conservative...

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Shapiro-Wilk test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test) the sample is not normally distributed. [D'Agostino's K-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Agostino%27s_K-squared_test) is a weaker test, which is sensitive mainly to kurtosis and skeweness. That this test does not produce a significant result does not mean that the distribution is normal, but only that we have no particularly strong evidence that it is skewed (I am not sure whether the implementation used is sensitive to kurtosis.)

E.g., it could be a symmetric but long-tailed distribution or a symmetric distribution with the shape of the central peak different from normal, etc.

A good idea when discussing normality is to visualize the data via a histogram or boxplot, to get the idea what it looks like. Also, As noted in the comments, strict normality is rarely necessary - one can proceed as if the sample is normally distributed, just keeping in mind that the results might be less robust.